# How can I fix an issue with create-react-app where only node_modules, package.json, and package-lock.json are created?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I know there are other previous posts on this. However, they are from a few years ago, making them somewhat outdated. The issue I am having just started as of May 2, 2022.

If I run npx create-react-app my-app, the only thing that gets created is the folder and two files mentioned in the question title. I've spent over an hour trying previous solutions to other questions and using other sources, but the issue is still not resolved. I was wondering if anyone could help me?

Thanks

Comment: This feels like a question for https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues, but that said: if things don't work, show things not working: add your install log to your post, so we know you read the whole thing and actually read what it said =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hard for me to answer without knowing the stack you have installed on your computer, however based on the information provided, you could be on your way!

From your terminal, I would try to navigate into the new app by:

```
`cd my-app`
```

Then, to start the server, run:

```
`npm start`
```

Here are some resources that I think will help you in your scenario:
https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Good luck buddy!

Comment: I think the OP is saying that only the module and package files are being created, which means there’s nothing to start.

Comment: That's interesting - Yes, I agree then - My above comment wont work. Logs would be a requirement to fully diagnosing and solving this. Thanks!

Comment: Between reactjs.org/docs/create-react-app.html and the link Mike put in a comment under my initial post, I finally got it figured out. I started having some health issues, so I don't remember exactly what I did, but it involved removing and reinstalling create-react-app@latest and a few other things. The problem has existed in the past from research I had done and had just started happening to me within the past week. Before this past week, I never had any issues.